# PHP file path extra dot

Tags: php

in a tutorial I am doing, the code below is in index.php file. Does the second "." in the file indicate that index.php is not at the root level? what would the significance be of adding extra "." in that position?

```
require_once("../includes/database.php");
```

Comment: ../ means that the file is located one level below your current working directory, if I understood the question correctly

Comment: @Sondre - typo - .. means "above", not "below". Though I suppose whether trees grow up or down is a matter of perspective. :)  So most generic to say "one fewer levels of directory than current before looking for the next path part".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a relative path to the current directory.

- "."  indicates the current directory
- ".." indicates one level up in the directory structure

So the answer is yes, that file is not in the root level.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily. For security reasons it is recommended that your include files be placed outside the web-accessible directory (htdocs), so minimizing the possibility of someone calling the *database.php* directly with forged parameters.

So the directory structure should look somthing like:

```
user
| |
| + htdocs
|   |
|   + index.php
|
+ includes
  |
  + database.php
```

Comment: "index.php is not at the root level" - It may be at the root level of your web-accessible directroy tree (htdocs), but definately not at the root level of your linux partition.

Comment: This is the right answer.  To add a quick note, this is not possible with GoDaddy shared hosting, but is possible with Dreamhost VPS.  I suspect that may be true with GoDaddy VPS as well, but I made the switch for other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

`..` means "one directory up"; `../..` would mean "two directories up".

Answer (score 1):

`..` references to relative path one level up the current path.